# Erro a mapear no EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, fluent-api

Boas,

Eu estou a tentar mapear uma base de dados com recurso a [EntityFramework-Reverse-POCO-Code-First-Generator](https://github.com/sjh37/EntityFramework-Reverse-POCO-Code-First-Generator) e uma das minhas views tem o seguinte mapeamento:

```
public VIEW_CODE_NAV_CustomerLedgerEntryMapping(string schema)
{
    ToTable("VIEW_CODE_NAV_CustomerLedgerEntry", schema);
    HasKey(x => new { x.DocumentType, x.DocumentNo_, x.ExternalDocumentNo_, x.RemainingAmount_LCY_stats_, x.Amount_LCY_stats_, x.PostingDate, x.Open, x.CustomerNo_ });

    Property(x => x.DocumentType).HasColumnName(@"Document Type").HasColumnType("int").IsRequired().HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
    Property(x => x.DocumentNo_).HasColumnName(@"Document No_").HasColumnType("nvarchar").IsRequired().HasMaxLength(20).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
    Property(x => x.ExternalDocumentNo_).HasColumnName(@"External Document No_").HasColumnType("nvarchar").IsRequired().HasMaxLength(35).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
    Property(x => x.RemainingAmount_LCY_stats_).HasColumnName(@"Remaining Amount _LCY_ stats_").HasColumnType("numeric").IsRequired().HasPrecision(38,20).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
    Property(x => x.Amount_LCY_stats_).HasColumnName(@"Amount _LCY_ stats_").HasColumnType("numeric").IsRequired().HasPrecision(38,20).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
    Property(x => x.PostingDate).HasColumnName(@"Posting Date").HasColumnType("datetime").IsRequired().HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
    Property(x => x.Open).HasColumnName(@"Open").HasColumnType("tinyint").IsRequired().HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
    Property(x => x.CustomerNo_).HasColumnName(@"Customer No_").HasColumnType("nvarchar").IsRequired().HasMaxLength(20).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
}
```

No entanto, quando eu vou a testar a aplicação, aparece-me este erro:

```
The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'FAMO.BaseItems.Database.urano.CODE.VIEW_CODE_NAV_CustomerLedgerEntry'. 
A member of the type, 'DocumentNo_', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.
```

Alguém me pode dar uma sugestão sobre o que fazer?

Comment: António, boa tarde!

Comentando sobre o erro que você obteve, seria prudente verificar se o tipo de dados/nome/tamanho do campo em questão,

> "DocumentNo_"

 tem no seu dataset, ele está reclamando exatamente disso.

Comment: @AngeloSimonato Eu se colocar o nome DocumentNo_ na view, ele funciona por isso eu sei que o problema esta relacionado com o nome da coluna. Eu gostaria de não ter que a alterar.

Comment: @AntónioGarcez, e qual é o nome do campo _DocumentNo__ na view?